# App crash with cryptic error code

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# application, but occasionally the GUI disappears (closes) without any warning. None of the exceptions catches seem to work, but I did notice the following error code in the VS output window:

> The program '[5172] MyProg.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has
>   exited with code -2146233082 (0x80131506)

I would be grateful if someone could please decipher this error code, as it would point me in the right direction. I couldn't find it in Microsoft's standard error code table.. Thanks.

Comment: It would be immensely helpful to know what the program is doing, what kind of program it is, what libraries it uses, what happens of the time of the close, if it happens on just your machine or others, etc -

Comment: In VS, go to Debugger->Exceptions and check all termpoarily. then you might now the point of intrigue

Comment: Any error starting with 0x8 is an invalid pointer.  It could be a null object or a pointer to an address outside your program.  Sometimes it occurs if the return type of a method doesn't match the type in the parent method causing a stack misalignment.  This shouldn't occur with the managed net library so I suspect you are using unmanaged code.

Comment: "If you turn on "Break when an exception is Thrown" for CLR Exceptions (Ctrl+Alt+E in VS), execution should break while you are debugging and the exception is thrown. This will probably give you some insight into what is going on." https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/549a9ce8-3017-469d-baa0-376e9b8da788/myappvshostexe-managed-v4030319-has-exited-with-code-1073741819-0xc0000005?forum=clr

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It seems like an Accessviolation error, which I have now traced to an external dll function.  Placing [System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute] around the calling function and implementing a try-catch has been quite a revelation!